# How to create a table title?

Tags: tables

I am astounded how difficult this is to achieve. I am using the `tabular` environment to some quite simple and nice results. Now I want to label my tables as in "Frubnicated widgets" with bolded centered letters right above the table. How can I do this without specifying all the little details?

Comment: There is no magic.  LaTeX doesn't read in your mind yet, and in a way or another, you have to tell what you want. Could you be more precise about what you want and what you've tried?

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Your question right now, is more than unclear. Do you want to give a caption (with numbered) to your table?

Comment: What is meant with title? The caption, i.e. `\caption{Frubnicated widgets}` or a line above the table content, e.g something like `\multicolumn{5}{c}{Frubnicated widgets}\tabularnewline` ?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: If you want to add a single centered field as part tabular, you can use \multicolumn.

Comment: You can center text the same way you'd center a table (`\begin{center} .. \end{center}` or `\centering`, depending on context), and you can get bold text with `\textbf{Frubnicated widgets}`. But which little details are you talking about? And is a (numbered) caption what you're actually after?